# Viewers Count in PDO json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, json

I can able to display list of product, but I want to show no of view count of the product from the view_product table

product_tbl table

```
----------------------------------
pro_id  |  product  | description  
----------------------------------
1       |  prodcut1 | description 
----------------------------------
2       |  prodcut2 |  description 
----------------------------------
3       |  prodcut3 |  description 
----------------------------------
```

view_product table

```
------------------------------------------
view_id |  username  | product  | view_time 
------------------------------------------
1       |  usename1 | prodcut1 | 2019-10-31 11:45:00 
------------------------------------------
2       |  usename2 | prodcut1 |2019-10-31 11:46:00
------------------------------------------
3       |  usename2 | prodcut1 |2019-10-31 11:45:00 
------------------------------------------
4       |  usename1 | prodcut1 |2019-10-31 11:46:00
------------------------------------------

$stmt = $conn->prepare("Select pro_id,product, description,qty from product_tbl");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt-> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$user_arr=array('data'=>$row);
echo json_encode($user_arr);
```

Based on product_id I want to view count of each product from the view_product table and Null valued row  if the product no t viewed, how can I use the below query in PDO json encode.

```
select count(id) as count1 from view_product where user_id=".$row['pro_id'].";
```

Expected Output as below

```
------------------------------------------------
pro_id  |  product  | description  | view count
------------------------------------------------
1       |  prodcut1 | description  | 2
------------------------------------------------
2       |  prodcut2 |  description | 2
------------------------------------------------
3       |  prodcut3 |  description | NULL
------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using n+1 queries, use a join statement instead in conjuction with `count()` function and in the end group them by a column.

```
SELECT 
  p.prod_id, 
  p.product, 
  p.description,
  COUNT(v.view_id) AS view_count
FROM product_tbl AS p
LEFT JOIN view_product AS v ON p.product = v.product
GROUP BY v.product
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, here I want to all the product in list event if it not visited also

Comment: @VijayKumar just change if to `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I can able get the output